# Get the same result from `dataframe/Dataset` functions as returned by SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

**Data :**

```
1,Coke
1,Beans
1,paper
2,Beans
2,Pen
2,Sheets
2,Banana
```

**Expected output** :

```
+---+------------------------+
|  1|Coke,Beans,Paper        | 
|  2|Beans,Pen,Sheets,Banana |
+---+------------------------+
```

I am able to achieve this by writing a sql query.

```scala
val df = sparkSession.read.csv("file_location")
df.registerTempTable("data")

val result = sparkSession
             .sql("select _c0   ,concat_ws(',', collect_list(_c1)) as product from data group by _c0")

result.show
```

Please help me in achieving  the same result using `dataframe/Dataset` functions (select, groupby , agg etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you have the answer right there, however I hope I'm not just doing some kind of postgraduate homework. A `DataFrame` is like *SQL* table, thus you can query it using its methods.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(List(
  (1, "Coke"),
  (1, "Beans"),
  (1,"paper"),
  (2,"Beans"),
  (2,"Pen"),
  (2,"Sheets"),
  (2,"Banana")
)).toDF("id", "product_name")

df.groupBy("id").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("product_name")).as("product_list")).show()
```

The output is:

```
+---+-----------------------+
|id |product_list           |
+---+-----------------------+
|1  |Coke,Beans,paper       |
|2  |Beans,Pen,Sheets,Banana|
+---+-----------------------+
```